# Проблема с отправкой POST запроса

Tags: angularjs, post

Доброго дня. Пробую выполнить POST запрос, но данные post параметра похоже просто не уходят, т.к. отправляя POST через обычную html форму возвращается корректный ответ. Где я мог допустить ошибку?

```
app = angular.module('testApp', []);
app.controller('TestCntr', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.items = [];
      $http({
             method: 'POST',
             url: 'http://portal.com/comp/api/',
             data: {md2: "74c32512c6c700672652fbcc7db70d18"}
             })
                .then(function(response) {
                 console.log(response.data);
                 $scope.items = response.data;
                 });
            }]);
```

Comment: Ну да, он же у вас просто в контроллере дергается. Вам нужно отправлять запрос сразу при открытии страницы?

Comment: Сразу при открытии.

Comment: если используется `ngRoute` то можно воспользоваться методом `resolve`, в этом случае в контроллер можно будет передать заполненный объект *items*, кстати а почему Вы не используете *сокращенную версию*, т.е. `$http.post(url, data).then()`?

Comment: Маршрутизация происходит без ngRoute

Comment: Приведите пример сокращённой версии

Comment: в документации [`$http.post(url, data).then()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post);

Comment: Буду использовать сокращённый вариант. Правда с передачей самого post параметра результата так и нет.

Comment: Есть ещё варианты передачи поста?

Comment: Этот вызов положите в `$scope.postOnLoad` и вызывайте `postOnLoad` где-нибудь в `ng-init`.

Comment: Я в ангуляре только начинаю работать. Не могли бы Вы привести пример. Спасибо Вам за помощь!

Comment: Возможно он вызывается, но происходит ошибка на стороне сервера. Поскольку в вашем случае не происходит обработка ошибок, вы ничего не видите. Попробуйте после `then` написать `.catch(function(err){console.log(err)})`.